# How to restrict visibility of domain properties in grails?

Tags: api, grails, dns

Is there any recommended way to restrict the visibility of a domain in grails?

Normally you you do something like to get some interface for external use:

```
def productList = Product.list()
withFormat {
  html {[productList:productList]}
  json { render productList as JSON }
  xml { render productList as XML }
  rss { render(feedType:"rss", productList)}
}
```

which is equal to

```
SELECT * FROM product
```

But by default there proerties in a domain that should not be populated. So I need something to say

```
SELECT id, name, foo1, foo2 FROM product
```

so only a list of properties is included in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a second domain class sort of like a view. The trick is to configure the mapping so it has the same table as the Product class:

```
class ProductView {

   String name
   Foo foo1
   Foo foo2

   static mapping = {
      table 'product'
   }
}
```

Then use that in your UI:

```
def productList = ProductView.list()
withFormat {
  html {[productList:productList]}
  json { render productList as JSON }
  xml { render productList as XML }
  rss { render(feedType:"rss", productList)}
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way like using AOP? Or a plugin allowing that?

Comment: ah good idea but kind of hack, because this is not very flexible. what about performance of it, does hibernate support creation of views?

Comment: The performance is the same as any domain class - Hibernate does a select with just the defined fields. You can map a view but it's tricky since it'll try to create the "table" when using update or create-drop.