# How to exclude params from XML rendered in Grails?

Tags: ajax, grails

I have a class :

```
class Category {
  String name
  SortedSet items
  static hasMany = [items:Item]
}
```

Inside the controller, I render category as XML (converters) :

```
   def getCategory = {
     render Category.read(1) as XML
   }
```

But I want exclude items from the rendering.

How can I do ?

Thanks

Comment: I know it is possible to use 
render(contentType(text/xml) and create manually xml content, but it's not elegant. 

Perhaps another method exist (configuration file, SpringBean,...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply return a `Map` with only the properties you want to include:

```
def getCategory = {
    def category = Category.read(1)
    render [ id: category.id, name: category.name ] as XML
}
```

Comment: It's not very elegant. Because if I have a book collection, I must iterate.
Book.list().each{ ... }

Comment: But it's the better solution. Thx

Comment: You should use collect() method, not each().

For example:

Book.list().collect{ book -> [ name: book.name ] } as XML

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a second domain class sort of like a view and configure the mapping so it has the same table as the `Category` class

See the entire answer on this thread : [How to restrict visibility of domain properties in grails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789176/how-to-restrict-visibility-of-domain-properties-in-grails/)

Fabien.

Comment: why not. But It's more elegant if I can configure a collection of xml 
view for my object. Your solution is a trick but is not really object oriented.

Why does not create a wrapper :

XMLView(object){
  static view1 = {
     object.params1
     object.params2
  }
  static view2 = {
    object.params2
    object.params3
  } 
}

May be can I create an issue on the jira codehaus for this ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the [marshallers plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/marshallers). It lets you define a custom marshaller either on the object itself or elsewhere. For example:

```
class Category {
  String name
  SortedSet items
  static hasMany = [items:Item]
  static marshallers {
    shouldOutputIdentifier false
    shouldOutputVersion false
    shouldOutputClass false
    elementName 'category'
    attribute 'name'
  }
}
```